# Problems with X-forwarding and nvidia driver for ssh -X

Tags: nvidia, ssh, xserver, x11-forwarding

I have just digged out a T430 Lenovo Notepad with a dockingstation. After installing the nvidia-384 driver through Settings > Software ... > Additional Drivers, I got it running on my 2 screen setup *yay!

However this is my office PC and I am accessing a Workstation as well. SSH does a perfect job, but if I try to forward spyder (for Python) to my machine, it would say:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

I then reinstalled mesa-utils

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

and the error changed. Now, if I log into the server and start the program, I get

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[17689:17737:0412/162127.329691:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(240)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
```

The starting window of spyder will pop to the screen but get's stuck afterwards.
Setting

```
unset LC_ALL
```

like supposed for some gaming-issues did not solve the problem.

I did some copy-pasting, but I do not understand the problem anymore and instead of messing up my Ubuntu, I decided to ask you for help. 
Appreciate any comments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do programs like xclock forward?  Maybe spyder is not an X program.

Comment: You're right @ubfan1. _xlcock_ works fine, but _Spyder_ does on other machines without the nvidia graphic cards as well. Any idea, where the problem could be?